# Android ClassCastException getting VIew

Tags: android

I am trying to do one main activity slider over next one.

I have Layouts structure in xml and after I try to get Button View instance, but I get next error and don't know resolve it.

Error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
```

activity_home

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cad000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#876000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#cecece"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSlide"
                style="@style/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="X" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

HomeActivity

```
Button btnSlide;
LinearLayout leftView;
LinearLayout mainView;
SliderAnimation slideAnimation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    leftView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.leftView);
    mainView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);

    btnSlide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSlide);
    btnSlide.setOnClickListener(this);

this.slideAnimation = new SliderAnimation(this);
    this.slideAnimation.initializeFilterAnimations(this.mainView, this.leftView);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you cleaned your project entirely and tested again ?

Comment: How can i clean and build project in eclipse? (I use Netbeans for everything)

Comment: @Dani Choose Run > Clean and Build Project (Shift-F11)

Comment: `ant clean`, from the command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your project from eclipse. This will probably solve your problem.

**To clean project :**

> 1. Select your project from your project list.
> 2. Now go to `Project -> Clean...`

select single or all project to clean. This will clean your project and will solve your problem.